# How to bind data to image src attributes in Vue3?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

Here is the issue I am having:

For a uni project, I am trying to upload image files to my backend (which is in my frontend project folder, I know it's bad I just thought this is the quickest way to do it since it's just a small uni project) and then view those image files in a page.

File uploads work alright and their main structure is that they create a new folder under a parent uploads folder with the name of the user who is currently logged in and save the image there.

So for fetching the images I also send a post request to my backend that includes the logged in username.

The response from the backend is an array of strings. The strings' general structure (which in frontend I decided to convert from backward slashes to forward slashes, which is also bad practice I know) is as below:

```
../../../uploaded_images/${username}/${filename}
```

Here is the relevant fronted post request below:

```
methods: {
    getImagePaths() {
        this.images = [];
        const username = this.username;

        axios.post('/api/getimages', { username })
            .then((response) => {
                const newImagePaths = response.data.imagePaths.map( path => {
                    return path.replace(/\\/g, '/');
                })

                console.log('Image Paths:', response.data.imagePaths);
                newImagePaths.forEach((item) => {
                    this.images.push(item);
                    console.log(item);
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error fetching image paths:', error);
            })
    }

}
```

The `this.images` in the code is initially an empty array in my data().

In the template, I tried to view the images like this:

```
<div class="p-3 row">
    <div class="p-3 col-2 photo-container" v-for="(item, index) in images" :key="index">
        <img :src="'../../' + item" class="photo-image img-fluid" @click="console.log(item)">
    </div>
</div>
```

And from this, I get a GET 404 Not Found error that is unrelated to my backend.

```
GET http://localhost:9090/uploaded_images/{username}/Cat03.jpg
```

I have seen solutions that include using `require()` but when I used it in my Vue template section, I started seeing unrelated backend errors on my browser and it made no sense to me. It was stuff like "log is declared but never used".

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: The best practice is to deal data in backend, and view data in frontend, so this question is that backend did't provide the correct url,why dont you test the url in the browser address bar befor send to frontend?

Comment: I see. Since everything about my project (database, backend, frontend) are crammed up in one project folder I thought that I could just straight up use the relative path of the images. But I guess I have to actually send images as blobs and parse them in my frontend script. Thank you for the advice!